# how to calculate this problem please help me with steps

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Person A can finish one task in 10 days. What if he work 10% faster for first day how much time it takes to finish the work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since he finishes $1$ task in $10$ days, he finishes $\frac{1}{10}$ of a task in $1$ day. $10%$ more than $\frac{1}{10}$ is just $\frac{11}{100}$ on the first day. So, we want to solve $\frac{11}{100}+\frac{d-1}{10}=1$ where $d$ is the amount of days now needed. We have $11+10d-10=100$, so $d=\frac{99}{10}$, so $\frac{99}{10}$ days or $14256$ minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be the speed in tasks per day. It's given that $$v=\frac{1}{10}.$$ Now we're asked about find the $x$ in $$1\cdot\left(\dfrac{11}{10}v\right)+(x-1)\cdot v=1,$$ can you finish from here?